# Is PostgreSQL (via ElephantSQL) a much slower database than Django's SQLite, and what to do about it?

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite, django-views, django-postgresql

I am building a Django webapp including a view, which can upload data into the database through a csv-import. Each import contains around 2,000 rows and 9 columns with DecimalFields and CharFields. So far I've been using Django's SQLite Database and each upload took me 1 min max. I switched to PostgreSQL (hosted via ElephantSQL) and now the upload takes at least 10 minutes. I've read in some posts that SQLite is faster than PostgreSQL but I was not expecting anything of this magnitude. Is there a way to speed up the upload process in PostgreSQL? I thought one reason for the low speed might be that I am using ElephantSQL's free Tiny Turtle Plan, but if i understand correctly the non-free plans differ only in terms of the max size of the database but not its speed? See also here https://www.elephantsql.com/plans.html

Might it be a solution to have PostgreSQL installed locally instead of using a cloud provider? Is there anything else I can optimize to speed up the process?

my model:

```
class Testdata3(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    mnemonic = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    assetclass = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=255, decimal_places=25)
    performance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=255, decimal_places=25)
    performance_exccy = models.DecimalField(max_digits=255, decimal_places=25)
    performance_abs = models.DecimalField(max_digits=255, decimal_places=25)
    performance_abs_exccy = models.DecimalField(max_digits=255, decimal_places=25)
    date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.key
```

my view:

```
def file_upload(request):
    template = "upload.html"
    prompt = {
        'order': 'Order of the CSV should be "placeholder_1", "placeholder_2", "placeholder_3" '
    }

    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, template, prompt)

    csv_file = request.FILES['file']

    if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
        messages.error(request, 'This is not a csv file')

    data_set = csv_file.read().decode('UTF-8')

    io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)

    #Ignores header row by jumping to next row
    next(io_string) 

    for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=';', quotechar="|"):
        # Check if csv-row is empty, if true jump to next iteration/row
        if all(elem == "" for elem in column):
            next
        else:
            _, created = Testdata3.objects.update_or_create(
                key = column[0],

                defaults = {
                'key' : column[0],
                # Get everything after the date part in the primary key
                'mnemonic': re.findall(r'AMCS#[0-9]*(.*)', column[0])[0],
                # Create datetime object from a string
                'date' : datetime.datetime.strptime(column[6], '%d/%m/%Y'),
                'assetclass' : column[10],
                'value' : column[16], 
                'performance' : column[19],
                'performance_abs' : column[20],
                'performance_abs_exccy' : column[30],
                'performance_exccy' : column[31],
                }
            )
        context = {}

    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: in anycase you should probably use [bulk_create|bulk_update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. I guess there is some problem with your service provider, or the CSV file you are importing is very large. I  use AWS RDS with Postgres and that is fast enough. It is nothing related to SQLite vs Postgres. Also, it can be because of your disk's IO speed which can be very high for SSD and high-end machines.